# Dockerfile: sudo apt-get install snmp asks if iptable rules should be saved, after the answer the process does not continue

Tags: dockerfile

During the build process with Docker Build I am asked if I want to save iptable rules. (see output below). Nothing happens after I give the answer.

I tried to download snmp in a running container and the question does not show up ?!

OUTPUT:

> Current iptables rules can be saved to the configuration file
> /etc/iptables/rules.v4. These rules will then be loaded automatically >during
> system startup.
>
> Rules are only saved automatically during package installation. See the >manual
> page of iptables-save(8) for instructions on keeping the rules file up-to->date.
>
> Save current IPv4 rules? [yes/no]

Dockerfile

```
FROM debian:latest

RUN apt-get update -y

RUN apt-get install -y locales && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && localedef -i en_US -c -f UTF-8 -A /usr/share/locale/locale.alias en_US.UTF-8 

ENV LANG en_US.utf8


RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y apt-utils \
                        vim \
                        tshark \
                        iperf \
                        iperf3 \
                        hping3 \
                        net-tools \
                        iptables-persistent \
                        iputils-tracepath \
                        openssh-client \
                        tmux \
                        snmp 
    
    

CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

Comment: I got the same problem with Ubuntu 16.04 Docker image

Answer (score 1):

So i fixed it in my case..

Somehow the installation process of the mentioned packages in the Dockerfile is crazy.

I modified my Dockerfile so that I first install apt-utils in one layer, then all packages except snmp in another layer and snmp seperate in one layer.

let me know if it worked for u as well